display of € characters when reading a file
I am trying to display all the contents of a text file but I am having problems
a certain character like the € is not displayed well it is displayed like that Ôé¼ but I want it to be displayed like that €
the code of my function:
int FileReadNotWrite2(char name[]){
    FILE *files = NULL;
    files = fopen(name, "r");
    if(files == NULL){
        int answer = MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Impossible to open the file.", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }else{
        char Carack;
        while ((Carack = fgetc(files)) != EOF){
            printf("%c", Carack);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(files);
    return 0;
}

I tried to do this
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

and I expect that all the characters that can be read but that it distorts, that it reads them correctly
like that I could read the € and other characters which are not displayed well

Stack Overflow is an English-only website. As there is no French language Stack Overflow site please edit to translate and your question may be reopened, assuming it meets other criteria for being on-topic here. Suggested reading: [ask]

fgetc() and fprintf() operate on byte characters (generally ASCII), for wide characters you need fgetwc() and wfprintf().

anonime tina, After setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");, try using wint_t fgetwc(FILE *stream); and save as a wint_t Carack.  Then print with fputwc().

Note that what you see will depend on what code set your terminal display is set to work with.  It looks like it is set for ISO 8859-1 rather than Unicode (UTF-8).  The problem is like external to your program, therefore.  However, with that said, I think the characters "Ôé¼" map to bytes 0xD4 0xE9 0xBC (correct for 8859-1), whereas the Euro symbol U+20AC is encoded as bytes 0xE2 0x82 0xAC in UTF-8, so I'm not sure what is happening (one reason this is a comment and not an answer).

char Carack; should be int Carack;  Characters are only char when stored in memory,  Also, EOF is an int, not a char.  If your file contains a character whose 8-bit value looks like an EOF, your program will terminate prematurely, since you'll mistake it for an actual EOF.  That won't happen if you leave the value as an int rather than discarding important information by converting it to a char.
